# r knitting error in parse(text=x, srcfile=src)

Tags: r, parsing, error-handling, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to knit an rmarkdown file to pdf in rstudio. When knitting, the system processes until it comes to the line of code in the picture below:

[image: Line of Code]

When the program reaches this line, the following error occurs:

[image: Error Message]

This error occurs wherever I define a new variable like "highPerc". I even tried deleting the variable and substituting its fixed value where it appears in my code. Can you help me understand why this error is occurring, and if there is a proper fix to resolve it? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code and error message here.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple, minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.